# Sharing a MTLCommandBuffer across multiple MTKViews

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, graphics, metal

I am using MTKViews for select UI elements inside of my UIKit app. I have a central metal controller that does something somewhat like this:

```
public class MetalView: MTKView                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   {

    var id:Int? = nil
    func getBuffer() -> MTLCommandBuffer {
        if (id == nil) {
            id = MetalView.idCounter
            MetalView.idCounter += 1
            MetalView.frameRegistry.append(id!)
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }

        if MetalView.frameRegistry.contains(id!) {
            MetalView.frameRegistry.removeAll()
            if let buffer = MetalView.savedBuffer {
                buffer.commit()
                buffer.waitUntilCompleted()
            }
            MetalView.savedBuffer = MetalView.queue.makeCommandBuffer()
        }
        MetalView.frameRegistry.append(id!)
        return MetalView.savedBuffer!
    }

    static private var savedBuffer:MTLCommandBuffer? = nil
    static private var frameRegistry:[Int] = []
    static private var idCounter:Int = 0

}
```

Each metal UI Element subclasses this gets its own id allowing it to call getBuffer in its draw function to get the frame's command buffer.

This code is based on two assumptions

1. Each MTKView gets its own drawable
2. You should only make one MTLCommandBuffer per frame

That is how I understand things to work.

Unfortunately this is creating a fairly obvious synchronization error with the textures

[image]

This should be a gradient of uniform hue but the hue was rapidly switched and as a result this tearing is left with one part drawing a different hue than the other.

So I suppose my questions are:

1. Are my assumptions correct
2. What is the proper way to share a MTLCommandBuffer across Metal drawing objects when not all of them may need to draw every frame.
3. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Your question needs to be improved. First of all, you do not say which hue is expected. Please state that! Second, please do tell how the different MTKViews are placed in relation to one another and what hue you expect for each. Without this, I'm afraid you are not going to get any helpful answers.

Comment: A uniform hue is expected and this is just one MTKView

Answer (score 0):

Apple clearly states that MTLCommandBuffer's can only be used once and once committed should not be reused. From the Metal programming Guide:

> Command buffers are **transient single-use objects and do not support reuse**. Once a command buffer has been committed for execution, the only valid operations are to wait for the command buffer to be scheduled or completed.

Thus, what you are doing is not supported. The only objects that allow reuse are:

- Command queues
- Data buffers
- Textures
- Sampler states
- Libraries
- Compute states
- Render pipeline states
- Depth/stencil states

Source: [Metal Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Cmd-Submiss/Cmd-Submiss.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH3-SW1).

A possible solution to your problem is to enqueue one MTLCommandBuffer per drawable via the same Command Queue. To learn how to enqueue two different command buffers and ensure the order they are executed, you should check Apple's ObjectExample sample code. You can download it from [here](https://github.com/nicolas-miari/Dissecting-ObjectsExample/tree/master/AdoptingMetalIIDesigningandImplementingaReal-WorldMetalRenderer/ObjectsExample).